# CakePHP directory redirection

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, redirect

How to prepare .htaccess file to block strange redirect...

When site is created in Cake, and we input address some like this: http://example.com/css, we are redirec to to http://example.com/app/webroot/css (403 Forbidden).

I think is the problem of .htaccess, but maybe no. The better solutions will be redirect to / or listing files if we can.

How solve this?

Comment: Why is that a problem - you likely don't want people do access your css directory.  If you access an actual file:  http://example.com/css/main.css it should work fine.

Comment: @Dave is right here,what you want to do and why?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Cake expects http://example.com/css to redirect to http://example.com/app/webroot/css, which is where you should be keeping all your css files.  You'll notice that doing things like echo $this->Html->css('style'); , the standard cake way for linking to a css style, it will create a link to http://example.com/css/style.css even though the file should be actually located in http://example.com/app/webroot/style.css.  You do not want people to be able to look at http://example.com/css, since that is your css folder.  If they can browse your file structure, they could potentially do bad things.  So don't alter your .htacess file.  As you said, whatever you're trying to do is most likely better done another way.